# Pandas: Cannot address column from previously merged multi level data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-level

After an data frame aggregation with group by I'm trying to "flatten" the headers into one to properly export the data as CSV:

```
df.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in df..columns.values]
df.columns
```

The output looks like that:

```
Index(['count', 'average', 'mean',
       'sum'],
      dtype='object')
```

If I call the data frame directly, I get a different information:

```
df
```

Output:

```
                 count average mean sum
col1 col2 col3 
...
```

It seems like pandas merged the column names, but I still have two levels of column description. If I try to address 2nd level columns, it raises an error:

```
df.drop('col1', axis = 'columns', level = 0)
```

Output:

```
AssertionError: axis must be a MultiIndex
```

Or

```
df.drop('col1', axis = 'columns')
```

Output

```
KeyError: "['col1'] not found in axis"
```

So it seems like I'm stuck with something in between. If I export the data frame to CSV and import it again, everything is fine:

```
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

And

```
df = df.load_csv('data.csv')
df.drop('col1', axis = 'columns')
```

So, what am I misunderstanding and doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do `df.reset_index()` after the `df.groupby` statement, to "flatten" the headers as requested. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html